# Loading DLC files in Python or C++ or Java

Tags: java, c++, python

Is there any Libraries that allow for loading of DLC files in Python Java or C++? 
FYI [link](http://jdownloader.org/knowledge/wiki/linkprotection/container/dlc-rsdf-and-ccf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jDownloader is written in java and handles DLC files.  Its open source.

http://jdownloader.org/knowledge/wiki/development/get-started
svn://svn.jdownloader.org/jdownloader/trunk

Comment: No, it's not open source. Only a part of it is open source. svn://svn.jdownloader.org/jdownloader/trunk contains that part, but there are many core non-open-source components.